# How to find "no" internet data while user has internet access in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, internet-connection

how to find whether user(ANDROID) has both internet connection AND internet data.
I knew that bellow code will check internet connectivity alone, but in my case internet access is there but the user had ran out of internet data....!

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

how  to identify whether the user has internet data balance or not...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can check internet access by following code. It will ping google and check internet access if internet is working then method will return true**

```html
public boolean isConnectingToInternetAccess(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                       try {
                             Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
                             int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
                             boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
                             return reachable;
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                       return true;
                      }
          }
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: how does this above code differs from just checking network availability alone, and does it takes more time for response(asking just because my project is little huge).....!

Comment: above code check internet access. If internet on and not working then above code method returns false.

Comment: yeah got it...;)

Answer (score 0):

> how to identify whether the user has internet data balance or not...?

Answer is, **you can not do that!**

Internet balance is provided through the mobile network operator in use. It depends on user balance, user available data, balance validity etc info which are privileged information and as a third party developer, you don't have access to those infos. All you can check if the user has internet access or not

Comment: i thought so too... ;)